# Is this a sneeze guard?

Tags: equipment

I'm about to start selling my baked goods at a farmers market, and I want to purchase a clear, portable,  acrylic sneeze guard - like that: 
[image]

The problem is, I can't find anywhere in the US/Canada that sells them. They are very common in the UK and Australia, but nowhere to be found here. I think I must have the wrong name.

Is somebody aware of a seller that has them, or if they go under a different name? I spent hours browsing the internet but can't find anything.

Comment: Not sure about the US term, but may I suggest a kind that has a top? So shaped more like a (sideways) ‘U’ instead of an ‘L’? Just protects a bit better and you can also use the top as a shelf for wrapped goods or decoration.

Comment: Have you tried amazon? https://www.amazon.com/s?k=sneeze+guard&i=garden&crid=2QMOW78THP7I0&sprefix=sneez+%2Cgarden%2C565&ref=nb_sb_ss_sc_1_6 seems to work good.

Comment: What's in your picture is not a sneeze guard.  A sneeze guard is clear acrylic, but it comes out horizontally and you often can reach under it.  I'm not sure what to call the item in your picture, but it protects against people touching ... someone leaning in and sneezing wouldn't be protected.

Comment: Sneeze guards I've seen focus more on protecting from the top than the front (which makes more sense). I actually think those are designed to prevent touching, not sneezing. These are the closest I could find to the exact match, but they are not specifically for food. https://www.displaysandholders.com/products/sign-holders-ad-frames/angled.html

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a bent acrylic sheet, may be sold as perspex or more common in the us Lucite which are just brand names of acrylic. Doing a google search for "bent acrylic sneeze guard" brought up a wealth of choices. Another term I've seen are Sneeze Screen. Ebay is a good place to start, others are [Manhattan Display](http://manhattandisplay.com/u-bend-24.html) and [Hubert](https://www.hubert.com/product/19816/Expressly-HUBERT-Bent-Acrylic-Sneezeguard-Top---26L-x-12W-x-9-14H).

These aren't hard to make with the right equipment, many acrylic supply shops will have an acrylic bender just for this sort of thing, you might be able to get them custom made to your spec locally.

Comment: Sneeze guards need not be "bent". Any angled piece will do.

Comment: Sure @Rob, you can use a frame instead. The ones in the picture supplied are bent acrylic, which the poster is trying to find.

Comment: @Rob: Just to be clear, the bent part is at the bottom (where the screen becomes the foot. You're right that this need not be the case (if the foot is made of another material); but I just wanted to point out that "bent" does not refer to whether it's curved or not; which is how I initially interpreted your comment.